# Search on the basis of dropdown values

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a dropdown in which I have two options, 
a. Selected
b. Not Selected.

I want whenever the user selects any option, the search should filter on that basis. I have a column of Selection in gridview which has both option Selected and Not Selected. The values are coming from the table.

Please see the  HTML of dropdown and button for your reference:

```
<div style="float: left;">
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSort" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlSort_SelectedIndexChanged">
        <asp:ListItem Text="--Select--" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="Selected" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="Not Selected" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:Button ID="btnSortSelection" runat="server" Text="Sort Selection" OnClick="btnSortSelection_Click" />
</div>
```

I tried with the below mentioned code but the page refreshes and the dropdown inside the gridview loses its value. So it did not returns my search result.:-

```
protected void ddlSort_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultSQLConnectionString"].ConnectionString); //create connection
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Career.Applicant where Selection =@Selected", conn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@selection", ddlSort.SelectedValue);
}
```

I want to stop the dropdownlist values to get postback and also it should work when sorted

Please see the code with Updated Panel:-

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="updateapplicants">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <div style="border: 1px solid #A8A8A8; width: 920px;">
                        <asp:GridView ID="gv_Applicants" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowPaging="true" Width="920"
                            PageSize="5" OnPageIndexChanging="gv_Applicants_PageIndexChanging" OnRowCommand="gv_Applicants_RowCommand"
                            EmptyDataText="No Applicants Found."
                            AllowSorting="true"
                            OnSorting="gv_Applicants_Sorting"
                            OnRowDataBound="gv_Applicants_RowDataBound" RowStyle-CssClass="a12" AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="a22" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" CssClass="table_box" HeaderStyle-Height="35px" DataKeyNames="JobId">
                            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#F0F0F0" />
                            <Columns>

                                <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="First Name" HeaderStyle-Width="84" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="Last Name" HeaderStyle-Width="106" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="ContactNumber" HeaderText="Contact" HeaderStyle-Width="98" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Email" HeaderText="Email" HeaderStyle-Width="150" />

                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Position" SortExpression="Position" HeaderStyle-Width="107">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <%# Eval("Job.Position") %>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Location" SortExpression="Location" HeaderStyle-Width="100">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <%# Eval("Job.Location") %>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="AppliedDate" DataFormatString="{0:MMMM dd, yyyy}" HeaderText="Date of Application" ReadOnly="true" HeaderStyle-Width="121" />

                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:LinkButton ID='lnkView' CommandName='v' Text='View' runat='server' CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ApplicantId") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
                                        |
                        <asp:LinkButton ID='lnkdel' CommandName='d' Text='Delete' runat='server' CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ApplicantId") %>' OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure to delete?');"></asp:LinkButton>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Selection">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSelection" runat="server" EnableViewState="true" AutoPostBack="true">
                                            <asp:ListItem Text="None" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem Text="Selected" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem Text="Not Selected" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
                                        </asp:DropDownList>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="JobId" HeaderText="Job ID" Visible="false" ReadOnly="true" />

                            </Columns>
                            <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
                            <FooterStyle BackColor="#D8DADA" Font-Bold="True" />
                            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#D8DADA" Font-Bold="True" />
                            <PagerStyle BackColor="#D8DADA" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                            <RowStyle BackColor="white" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderColor="#a8a8a8" BorderWidth="1px" Height="35" />
                            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                        </asp:GridView>

                    </div>
                    <br />

                    <br />

                    <div id="divDetails" runat="server" class="force-overflow">
                        <div class="scrollbar" id="style-1">

                            <div style="border-left: 1px solid #A8A8A8; border-right: 1px solid #A8A8A8;">

                                <asp:DetailsView ID="dv_Applicants" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#F7E1E1" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="false" AllowPaging="false"
                                    HeaderText="Applicant Details" OnDataBound="dv_Applicants_DataBound" Width="912px" BackColor="#F0F0F0" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1" BorderColor="#F0F0F0"
                                    RowStyle-Height="30" Font-Size="10">
                                    <Fields>

                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Position" HeaderStyle-CssClass="c_width">
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <%#Eval("Job.Position") %>
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Location" HeaderStyle-CssClass="c_width">
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <%#Eval("Job.Location") %>
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Business Unit" HeaderStyle-CssClass="c_width">
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <%#Eval("Job.BusinessUnit") %>
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="First Name" HeaderStyle-Width="190" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true" />
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="Last Name" HeaderStyle-Width="190" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true" />
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="ContactNumber" HeaderText="Contact" HeaderStyle-Width="190" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true" />
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Email" HeaderText="Email" HeaderStyle-Width="190" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true" />
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="PAN" HeaderText="PAN" HeaderStyle-Width="190" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true" />
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="DOB" DataFormatString="{0:MMMM dd, yyyy}" HeaderText="Date of Birth" HeaderStyle-Width="190" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true" />
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Graduation" HeaderText="Graduation" HeaderStyle-Width="190" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true" />
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="GradOther" HeaderText="Other" HeaderStyle-Width="190" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true" />
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="GradDate" DataFormatString="{0:MMMM dd, yyyy}" HeaderText="Graduation Date" HeaderStyle-Width="190" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true" />
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="PostGraduation" HeaderText="Post Graduation" HeaderStyle-Width="190" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true" />
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="PGOther" HeaderText="Other" HeaderStyle-Width="190" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true" />
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="PGDate" DataFormatString="{0:MMMM dd, yyyy}" HeaderText="Post Graduation date" HeaderStyle-Width="190" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true" />
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="AnyOtherQual" HeaderText="Any Other Qualification" HeaderStyle-Width="190" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true" />
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="CurrentOrg" HeaderText="Organization" HeaderStyle-Width="190" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true" />
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="CurrentDesignation" HeaderText="Designation" HeaderStyle-Width="190" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true" />

                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="CurrentFunctionalDesig" HeaderText="Current Functional Designation" HeaderStyle-Width="190" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true" />

                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="CurrentCTC" DataFormatString="{0} lakhs per annum" HeaderText="CTC" HeaderStyle-Width="190" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true" />
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="YrsinCurrentRole" HeaderText="Current Experience" HeaderStyle-Width="190" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true" />
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="TotalExp" HeaderText="Total Experience" HeaderStyle-Width="190" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true" />
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="KeySkills" HeaderText="Skills" HeaderStyle-Width="190" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true" />
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City" HeaderStyle-Width="190" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true" />
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="State" HeaderText="State" HeaderStyle-Width="190" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true" />
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Country" HeaderText="Country" HeaderStyle-Width="190" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true" />
                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Willing to Relocate" ControlStyle-CssClass="c_width" HeaderStyle-CssClass="c_width">
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("WillingtoRelocate")) == true ? "Yes" : "No" %>
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="LocationPreference" HeaderText="Location Preference" HeaderStyle-Width="190" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true" />
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="AppliedDate" DataFormatString="{0:MMMM dd, yyyy}" HeaderText="Date of Application" ReadOnly="true" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true" />
                                        <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="CVFilePath" Text="View Resume" ControlStyle-ForeColor="White" ControlStyle-CssClass="bg" Target="_blank" />
                                    </Fields>
                                </asp:DetailsView>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Can you tell me where did yo bind your grid from the database ? (it means you bind gridview in `Page_Load` event ?)

Comment: I haven't written code for binding from the DB.

Comment: @Nadeem Use Update Panels

Comment: @Ganesh_Devlekar: my gridview is inside update panel only.Please suggest some idea

Comment: @Paste that code with gridview...update panel....

Comment: @Ganesh_Devlekar: see the modified question, In last code section i have added the code with update panel

Comment: See the code I tried, not working private void loadSearch(){string iselection = ddlSort.SelectedValue ;SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultSQLConnectionString"].ConnectionString);iselection = @"Select * from Career.Applicant where Selection='@Selected'";SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(iselection,conn);da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@Selection",SqlDbType.VarChar,25).Value = "%" + iselection + "%";DataSet ds = new DataSet();da.Fill(ds);gv_Applicants.DataSource = ds;gv_Applicants.DataBind();}

Comment: You can't do like this `loadSearch()` you will always get iselection as  NULL

Comment: can you let me know any other way to do this ? Please